# getting 'TypeError: Plotly.plot(...) is undefined' when using 'Plotly.addTraces'

Tags: javascript, plotly

On my plotly bar chart, I have added a click event and in that callback I
want to add new bars (traces) to the chart.

(So, when the user clicks on a bar in the chart, more bars are added to show more details.)

But.... I get the console log stack trace:
[image]

Which is weird because in the debugger, I can see an object Plotly.plot in 
the global scope.

Is this a bug in plotly.js?  The code lines in question are:

[image]

It really is undefined at that point... confirmed by printing to the
console.

Could it be because I'm calling it from within a click event callback?
Here's a code frag to demonstrate - it will take some time to work up 
a full jsfiddle test case:

```
  var myPlot = document.getElementById('graph0');
  myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
        Plotly.addTraces('graph0', 
              [{ "x":[1453939532000],
                "y":["40727716"],
                "showlegend":false,
                "orientation":"h",
                "marker":{"color":"rgba(255,0,255,1)"},
                "name":"40727716",
                "type":"bar"}],
              [25] ) ;
        return true;
  });
```

Any pointers to debug this would be appreciated!

Comment: Additional info:   while debugging I stepped through the code and discovered the issue is related to plotly behavior.  It thinks I am 'draggin' the mouse.  It adds the new trace, but must also be triggering a drag action on the mousedown event.  I need to find a way to turn off this behavior temporarily....

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the your original `Plotly.plot` (or `Plotly.newPlot`) call? Looks like by the time `addTraces` is the `graph0` div lost is plotly.js specific class resulting in this error.